# Получение данных из одной страницы и передача другой расширение Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте. 
Как можно организовать логику:

1. напрямую: из `context_script_2.js в context_script_1.js`
2. как то через: `xhr.open("GET", "http://site.ru/", true);`
3. из background.js в context_script_2.js запрос на получение данных, получив в background.js данные, передать в context_script_1.js   Как то данный пункт кажется сложным.

Comment: цель какая? Что реализовать хотите?

Comment: цитата: Что реализовать хотите?                                                 Передача данных из одной вкладки другой, или из одного: context_script_2.js  другому: context_script_1.js